# My website just show selector in Bootstrap 3 although my Bootstrap version is 4.5

Tags: css, web, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

My project has been updated bootstrap 3 to bootstrap 4. But it's just showed selector bootstrap 3.
I want the header of table background is black and text is white but the background's still white and the text's still black.

This is my HTML code:

```
<table class="table-hover table">
  <tr class="bg-dark text-white">
    <th>
      <p>Mô tả sự cố</p>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p>Tên thiết bị</p>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p>Người thêm</p>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p>Người xác nhận</p>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p>Trạng thái</p>
    </th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is result:

[image: Text]

I changed class of `<tr class="bg-danger text-info">` and the result:

[image: Text]

Comment: Actually, if you are using bootstrap 4 alone, it should work fine. Can you share your bootstrap import section for us?

Comment: As far as I understand, Bootstrap is using a `.table-dark` to achieve a dark table (bot header and columns), and a `.thead-dark` if you want just the header to be dark: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/

Could you try to use a `.thead-dark` and try if it works for you? If this is not the same, please share with us a fiddle of your work.

Comment: You can find an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/67ukbo3s/ I think that you could avoid adding an inner `<p>` inside your `<th>` because it's just adding unwanted padding to your design.

Comment: i use asp.net mvc so bootstrap is added automatically in file _Layout.html. When i created project, it's bootstrap 3. Then, i use NuGet to update Boostrap 4.5. The selectors of Bootstrap 3 work fine but 4 is not. Sorry guys, my English is so bad.

Comment: I tried to use tag <thead> and class .thread-dark but it not work